# render javascript on partialpostback through ajax

Tags: ajax, postback

I have a grid on a page along with a tooltip for each cell created dynamically on dlDrivers_ItemDataBound event through javacsript. I have been using ajax on my page.
When i visit the page for the first time, all the tooltips are working fine but when i perform some actions on the page and grid ispostback through ajax, but the javascript here is not rendered and the tooltip does not appear.

Can anybody give me some solution.........

Khushi

Answer (score 0):

You had to re-register the scripts you need:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "* nameScript *", "* scriptCode *", true)
```

just before the update of the UpdatePanel.